# How to pivot a pandas df where each column header is an hour and each row is a date

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas df that looks like this
[image]

where each column is an hour of the day noted in the date column. I would like to pivot this df so each hour of the day is its own row. Similar to this

[image]

where there would be 24 rows for every hour of each date.

I've tried to used pd.melt using the following

```
hourly_value = ['00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00','05:00','06:00','07:00','08:00','09:00','10:00','11:00','12:00']
df = df.melt(id_vars = ['DATE'], var_name = hourly_value, value_name = ('Hourly Precip'))
```

but keep getting error "IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2". I've also looked into using df.pivot but Im starting to think my df is in a much different format than most of the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get what you want is to:

1. Use [`.set_index('DATE')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to turn the `DATE` column into the index.
2. Use [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to bring the columns into the index as well, creating a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) where the row for each date gets inserted as a second level in the index.
3. Use `.reset_index()` to turn all index levels back into rows.

The following snippet illustrates:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = [f"1/{i}/2020" for i in range(1, 21)]
cols = ["DATE"] + [str(i) + ":00" for i in range(25)]
zeros = np.zeros((len(dates), len(cols) - 1))
data = list([[x] + list(y) for x, y in zip(dates, zeros)])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

df2 = (
    df.set_index("DATE") # makes the DATE column the index
    .stack()             # stacks 
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "Time", 0: "Value"})
)
print(df2.head())
```

Which outputs:

```
       DATE  Time  Value
0  1/1/2020  0:00    0.0
1  1/1/2020  1:00    0.0
2  1/1/2020  2:00    0.0
3  1/1/2020  3:00    0.0
4  1/1/2020  4:00    0.0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. now that I see that this is possible, how would I do this if I had 4 additional columns (I excluded them from the original df format) associated with each hourly measurement? Would I just continue though rename with `.rename(columns = {'level_1':'Time',0:'Value', 1 :'Value 2 name',2:'Value 3 name'}` and so on?

Comment: `.stack()` puts **all** of the original columns into one column (the one named `0`), so I don't think it will work for your follow-up scenario. If you want the multiple values for each hour to be separate columns in the final result you could try separating the columns of the original DataFrame, applying the above procedure to each seperately, then merging them back together.

Comment: yep this is exactly how ive started to tackle the follow up. thanks for verifying my thoughts on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 pd.melt( df.reset_index(), id_vars=['DATE'], var_name='hour', value_name='Hourly Precip')
```

Comment: df.reset_index is what I was looking for. I tried to used reset index = True but kept getting an error because of it. I didnt know I could do it this way as well. This gave me the general format I was looking for although it still needs some manipulating. Thanks!